# Printing to PDF with correct file path and with correct file name

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a small macro that takes an daily Excel report and prints it to a specific printer (printing to PDF).  When I run the  macro, I am still missing the final steps.  Running it as is, I still need to click the "save" button that pops up, and have to navigate to the correct file path.  Is there a way to have it automatically hit the save button for me, and save the file into the correct folder (as seen in the code below)?

```
Sub printToPDF()

'declare variable for my file path
Dim filePath As String

'declare variable for my file name
Dim fileName As String

fileName = "Operations_Daily_Outage_Report_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
filePath = "M:\Daily_Outage_Report\Active"

Worksheets("general_report").PageSetup.CenterVertically = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="Foxit Reader PDF Printer"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an old enough version of Excel that you can't just save to a .pdf?  Or is there some other reason you're printing through a PDF driver?

Comment: You have three options : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-as-PDF-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110 or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx

Comment: If I simply save as a PDF, can I still set it up where the `PageSetup.CenterVertically = False` works?  Part of this is a learning exercise for me.

Comment: It's a simple one line change - try it - and then come back and tell us if it works the way you want it

Comment: @dbmitch I think he is saying more that I should try it in a different manner, so the one line switch does not really apply here.  I already have it in the code, so looking for a solution which works with my existing macro.

Comment: Who is he? @cyboashu has pointed out three possibilities - these are fairly simple to read and they have examples - you could try replacing your one line printout with the built-in Office SaveToPDF option - I posted one answer example - it should work just fine in your "existing macro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everyone is trying to give you answers that you can try out. I'm not sure why you can't just test it and tell us if it works for you?

If you have a reasonably new version of Access (within last 10 years), then you should be able to use the built-in Office PDF converter

**Change this line:**

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
```

**To This:**

```
Worksheets("general_report").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF _    
   FileName:=filePath & "\" & fileName Quality:=xlQualityStandard
```

***Come back and tell us if it worked for you.***

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It's not that I cannot do it, it is more that I am new to this.  And sometimes easy solutions for your eyes are not easy for mine.  We are all at different levels, and it is nice to learn as much as I can.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. Enjoy your future coding!